# Pandas issue in python 2.7.0

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have a running code on `Python 2.7.0` with `pandas==0.23.4`. Now when I am trying to deploy this on a new server, my df looks like below but my filter is not working? What is the issue here? This is a conda distribution. Can I reinstall python or is there a change in pandas implementation.

I tried `df.query()` as well but with no luck

```
data_df

  KPIID  CATEGORY ACTUAL_DATE
0    21  Delivery  2016-05-11
1    21  Delivery  2016-10-29
2    21  Delivery  2016-12-10
3    21  Delivery  2016-12-20
4    21  Delivery  2017-01-11
5    21  Delivery  2017-01-18
6    21  Delivery  2017-01-31
7    21  Delivery  2017-02-09
8    21  Delivery  2017-02-15
9    21  Delivery  2017-02-23
```

when i try :

```
data_df[data_df.KPIID == 21]
```

I am getting an empty DF :(

```
Empty DataFrame
  Columns: [KPIID, CATEGORY, ACTUAL_DATE]
  Index: []
```

I ran below code on new server

```
import sys
sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=7, micro=0, releaselevel='final', serial=0)


pd.__version__
'0.23.4'
```

Comment: Did you see the dtypes of your values?

For: data_df[data_df.KPIID == 21]
If your values are in String, it will possibly give empty dataframe as an output.

Comment: Check `df.dtypes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the column KPIID is an integer and not a string?

Try using dtypes to check the type of variable stored in this column

```
data_df.dtypes
```

If it is a string you should change it to

```
data_df[data_df.KPIID == '21']
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a feeling your KPIID values are not integer format.

Try this:

```
data_df.KPIID=data_df.KPIID.astype(int)
data_df[data_df.KPIID == 21]
```

Comment: You were right! I was too lame to expect this!

Comment: It's alright mate... happens with all of us.